# Rendering grid graphics in Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I have a short routine which arranges ggplot and grid graphics using the grid.arrange function in the package gridExtras. I need to render the output from my routine (which nominally prints using grid.draw, or returns the grid object as an option) in my Sweave documentation. I'm at a loss how to do this, since the say I've been using "print" doesn't work the same way as with a pure ggplot graphic. I've tried:

```
g <- ggkm(survfit.object, returns=T)
print(g)
```

where g is the object created by grid.arrange, and has class

```
> class(g)
[1] "frame" "gTree" "grob"  "gDesc"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Abhijit

Comment: if your function returns a `grob`, then you need to call `grid.draw(g)` rather than `print(g)`. In recent versions of `gridExtra`, you could also expect `print` to work with a method `print.arrange()` basically calling `grid.draw()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing the object as it's created rather than printing the saved object seems to work, although I couldn't explain why ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


<<>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

d <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=runif(10))
g1 <- qplot(x,y,data=d)
g2 <- qplot(x,z,data=d)
@ 

<<fig=TRUE,results=hide>>=
print(grid.arrange(g1,g2,ncol=2))
@ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've experienced this issue before as well. What platform are you working under? (windows? nix? mac?)

Comment: Ubuntu Linux -- but I don't see why this problem would be platform specific ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the platform, but rather the typesetting program you use for tex (ie, MikeTex on windows, MacTex for mac, LaTeX on Ubuntu). I've noticed some strange differences when I try to run the same sweave on one system vs. the next.

Comment: Have you tried taking the generated LaTeX file and moving it across platforms to test your hypothesis ... ?

Comment: Yes, the files I get from sweave when I type set them on windows look different than when I perform the same type set on ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think the `print()` was necessary here. `grid.arrange()` draws by default, similarly to other grid grobs, but unlike `lattice` or `ggplot2`.